# Add XML element in a child node if parent node meets a condition

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a very simple question for you experts of XML.
I want to add a new Element beside `tuple_centre_name`, with the same tag and different value,  only if the username have a value I want, and another  `tuple_centre_name` with the same value, here `amministrazione`, does NOT exist.
I ask you because I find difficult to reach that element,  check if another `tuple_centre_name` exists and **then check the parent attribute**.

I'm using DOM in JAVA.
Thanks for helping me.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><accounts>
    <account>
        <username>fabio</username>
        <password>123456</password>
        <node>
            <tuple_centre_name>amministrazione</tuple_centre_name>
            <port>NP</port>
        </node>
    </account>
```

Example is shown here. Request: add a new tuple_centre_name named `something else` only if it does not already exist inside the element named `fabio`. Here, is the result I want:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><accounts>
    <account>
        <username>fabio</username>
        <password>123456</password>
        <node>
            <tuple_centre_name>amministrazione</tuple_centre_name>
            <tuple_centre_name>Something else</tuple_centre_name> //ok because `fabio` as username is fine for me
            <port>NP</port>     
        </node>
    </account>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for this:

```
Document document = /* ... */;

final String username = "fabio";

XPathVariableResolver resolver = new XPathVariableResolver() {
    @Override
    public Object resolveVariable(QName varName) {
        return varName.getLocalPart().equals("user") ? username : null;
    }
};

Element newElement = document.createElement("tuple_centre_name");
newElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("amministraione"));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(resolver);

Node tupleCentreNameNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(
    "//account[username[text()=$user]]/node/tuple_centre_name",
    document,
    XPathConstants.NODE);

tupleCentreNameNode.getParentNode().insertBefore(newElement,
    tupleCentreNameNode.getNextSibling());
```

XPath usually looks like a directory path, which is where the `account/node/tuple_centre_name` part comes from.  The two slashes at the start (`//account`) means "any account element, any number of levels deep in the document."

The `account[username[text()=$user]]` selector means "an account element which contains a username element whose text matches the XPath variable 'user'."  XPath variables can be defined externally with an XPathVariableResolver.  While it is possible to hard-code the username value in the XPath expression, you would need to escape various characters, including quotes and characters which are special in XML;  passing the username as an XPath variable guarantees it will be correct.